# Automatic reference to the SVN changesets in Trac tickets

Tags: svn, trac

I have followed this guide: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/Ubuntu-11.04-Subversion#AutomaticreferencetotheSVNchangesetsinTractickets

I have no problem commiting and see it in tracs timeline... but if I use fixes or refs, it doesn't update the ticket.

Anyone have seen this before...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 0.12.x, you should rather follow [TracRepositoryAdmin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync) and [CommitTicketUpdater](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CommitTicketUpdater). If it still doesn't work, set the logging level to DEBUG and see what happens after a commit.